# Feature order when used with a trained machine learning model

Tags: machine-learning, pickle

Say I have a machine learning algorithm trained using features F1, F2 and F3. This model is then subsequently picked and used on another project (imported using Joblib).

When using the trained model, do the inputs need to be in the same order (F1, F2 or F3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity assume that you are fitting a linear model and a regression model (but generalizes to all the others). If `F1, F2, F3` are your features then it finds the weights `w1, w2, w3, bias` such that the error made by `w1*F1 + w2*F2 + w3*F3 + bias` is minimum. It is called the linear combination of weight and features.

So when making the prediction the model calcualtes the value `w1*F1 + w2*F2 + w3*F3 + bias` so the order of features matter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they must be in exactly the same order. And preprocessed in exactly the same way.